# To discuss continuity of $f_{yx}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Given 
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy^3}{x+y^2}, & (x,y) \neq (0,0),   \\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

Now I computed $$f_{yx} = \frac{5xy^4+y^6}{(x+y^2)^3}$$

Now I approach from $y=m\sqrt{x}$ and see limit depends on $m$. But I am not sure though.

Comment: Does $f_{yx}$ mean differentiated first with respect to $y$, then with respect to $x$, or the other way around?

Comment: other way arounf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you substitute $y=m\sqrt{x}$ you will find a formula that depends on $m$ and the limit along each curve $y=\sqrt{m}$ exists, but you get different values for different $m$, so the limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ does not exist.